# shell adding multiple lines within the middle of a file

Tags: string, bash, shell, cat

I am just wondering what is the best way to add multiple lines within a file. I.e. I want to replace a tag within a file i.e. /#tag

with multiple lines, say 3

```
echo "line 1"
echo "line 2"
echo "line 3"
```

I know I can read each line of the file and if I encounter the tag could pipe the new lines to the file, however, due to the size of the file, that takes way too long.

I am sure there must be a better way?

Comment: There's no fast way to do this, essentially the whole file has to be re-written.

Comment: What is the size of the file?  Do you know exactly where the new lines should go (e.g. line number), or do you need to read every line and determine where to insert the lines?

Comment: I dont know what line the tag will be on, but I know the format of the tag -thought it might be possible to grep for the tag then maybe insert at that point?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's:/#tag:line 1\nline 2\nline 3:' file
```

The `s` command is simply 'substitute', usually the separator would be a `/` but since this is in the tag we can use `:` instead. See http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html if you have never used `sed` before. The `/#tag` can be a regular expression, just as with `grep`.